# All IP's in a subnet (C)

Tags: c, networking, cidr, netmask

Does someone have a good example of a way I could take a IP address with a CIDR such as `192.168.1.1/24` and return all the ip addresses inside of that range such as `192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2, 192.168.1.3 ...`

I'm fine with it being returned in a array of `unsigned long`, a `char` or just something like

```
/* Pseudocode */
while(currnetip <= finalip) { 
    print(currnetip); 
    currnetip++; 
}
```

As long as I can understand it its fine.

Feel free to comment a link to a post if you think it could help me.

Edit: Probably worth mentioning I've found lots of stuff that calculated the broadcast address ect I'm just not sure how to link all those functions together.

Comment: There are only two current IPs: IPv4 and IPv6. I think you mean IP addresses, not IPs (Internet Protocols).

Comment: @Ron Maupin yes thats what I meant. Edited for clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, pack your IPv4 address into an `uint32_t` (defined in `<stdint.h>`), putting the leftmost octet in dotted-decimal notation into the most significat bits. For example,

```
uint32_t ipv4_pack(const uint8_t octet1,
                   const uint8_t octet2,
                   const uint8_t octet3,
                   const uint8_t octet4)
{
    return (((uint32_t)octet1) << 24)
         | (((uint32_t)octet2) << 16)
         | (((uint32_t)octet3) <<  8)
         |  ((uint32_t)octet4);
}
```

and its inverse,

```
unsigned char *ipv4_unpack(unsigned char *addr, const uint32_t packed)
{
    addr[3] = (uint8_t)(packed);
    addr[2] = (uint8_t)(packed >> 8);
    addr[1] = (uint8_t)(packed >> 16);
    addr[0] = (uint8_t)(packed >> 24);
    return addr;
}
```

An address like `128.64.32.16` is packed into `0x80402010` (128 == 80<sub>16</sub>, 64 == 40<sub>16</sub>, 32 == 20<sub>16</sub>, and 16 == 10<sub>16</sub>).

---

You need to also convert the [CIDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) prefix size (1 to 32) into a binary mask of that many highest bits set:

```
uint32_t ipv4_mask(const int prefix_size)
{
    if (prefix_size > 31)
        return (uint32_t)0xFFFFFFFFU;
    else
    if (prefix_size > 0)
        return ((uint32_t)0xFFFFFFFFU) << (32 - prefix_size);
    else
        return (uint32_t)0U;
}
```

Prefix 24 corresponds to a mask of 11111111111111111111111100000000 in binary, and 0xFFFFFF00 in hexadecimal.

Prefix 28 corresponds to a mask of 11111111111111111111111111110000 in binary, and 0xFFFFFFF0 in hexadecimal.

For address `addr1.addr2.addr3.addr4/prefix`, the first address in a range (typically the gateway address for said range) is

```
uint32_t first = ipv4_pack(addr1, addr2, addr3, addr4) & ipv4_mask(prefix);
```

and the last address (typically the broadcast address for said range) is

```
uint32_t last = ipv4_pack(addr1, addr2, addr3, addr4) | (~ipv4_mask(prefix));
```

In all cases, `first <= last`, and iterating from `first` to `last`, inclusive, and calling `ipv4_unpack()` to unpack the value into dotted-decimal notation), yields all IPv4 addresses within the range.

---

The same would work for IPv6, but requires something like an `uint128_t` type. (It can be emulated with smaller unsigned integer types, of course, taking a few more instructions, but the logic stays the same.)