# How to convert an address into a netmask(decimal)

Tags: c, netmask

So I did this thing like this :

```
for(i=1;i<=MASK;i++) // MASK IS THE ADDRESS
{
    MASKBINARY[i]=1; // CREATE AN ARRAY WITH 1s and 0s
}
for(i=8;i>0;i--)
{

    if(MASKBINARY[i-1]==1 && MASKBINARY[i]==0) // check if the next element is 1
    {
        k=i-1; // get the position to the first 1
        numar1=numar1 + powl(10,i-1);
    }
    if(MASKBINARY[i]==1 && i!=(8-k)) // check if your element is 1 and different from the first 1
    {
        numar1=numar1 + powl(10,8-i);
    }

}
printf("\n %d",numar1);
for(i=16;i>8;i--)
{

    if(MASKBINARY[i-1]==1 && MASKBINARY[i]==0 && numar1!=11111111)
    {
        k=i-9;
        numar2=numar2 + powl(10,17-i);
    }
    if(MASKBINARY[i]==1 && i!=k+8)
    {
        numar2=numar2 + powl(10,16-i);
    }

}
printf("\n %d",numar2);
for(i=24;i>16;i--)
{

    if(MASKBINARY[i-1]==1 && MASKBINARY[i]==0 && numar2!=11111111)
    {
        k=i-17;
        numar3=numar3 + powl(10,25-i);
    }
    if(MASKBINARY[i]==1 && i!=k+16)
    {
        numar3=numar3 + powl(10,24-i);
    }

}
printf("\n %d",numar3);
for(i=32;i>24;i--)
{

    if(MASKBINARY[i-1]==1 && MASKBINARY[i]==0 && numar3!=11111111)
    {
        k=i-25;
        numar4=numar4 + powl(10,33-i);
    }
    if(MASKBINARY[i]==1 && i!=k+24)
    {
        numar4=numar4 + powl(10,32-i);
    }

}
```

Basically what I did you take the address ( let's say it's 4 ) and I created an array with 1s and 0s ( made it a netmask binary ) . Then I converted that array into 4 variables ( numar1,2,3,4 ) which I transformed to base 10 ( from 2 ).
So if my address is 4 the output will be 240.0.0.0,exactly like here : https://www.iplocation.net/subnet-mask
The problem is this code is a real mess and VERY inneficient.
How can I transform that address into a netmask (decimal) efficiently ? Can I somehow work with the bits ? Something like , take the first 8 bits,convert them to base 10,take the next 8 bits convert them,take the next ... etc ?
Or I don't know,something that is not that ... bad

I am a noob,I know this is a mess

Comment: Aside: I don't have an answer but please get into the habit of placing the `newline` at the *end* of each `printf` expression, not at the beginning. What you have is not idiomatic and will mislead you when printing debugging cues.

Comment: would something like `htonl()` or `htons()` be of any help to you?

Comment: Your loops seem to be unaware that arrays in C are indexed between `0` and `LEN-1` although you have not graced us with the array definitions.

Comment: There are a lot of "magic numbers" in the code. Can you relate each to some kind of central reference? One thing, `numar2!=11111111` is not comparing to a binary number!

Comment: I have no idea what htonl is,internet is not helping me either.

Comment: added comments , numar2!=11111111 is becasue when you check if an element is 1 this code will check for the latest 1,which can be in the first/second/third octet ,that means this code will add a 10^8 after that 11111111 . Anyway,like I said,the code is a mess,I am looking for simpler answers :D

Comment: the arrays go up to 33 :) I know arrays are indexed between 0 and LEN-1,I kept it like this just to keep track of the elements easier

Comment: Yeah and [*ours go up to 11*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_to_eleven)!

Comment: I just answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40774610/1475978) how to use `uint32_t` (with first octet in dotted-decimal notation in most significant bits) for this. Is .. is this homework?

Comment: @NominalAnimal It is a homework but it is not mine,some friends have this homework ( I am not learning c in school , so I am  trying  to learn by myself ) :D

Answer (score 0):

Using a loop and some bitwise operators:

```
int mask = 0;
int addr; // get this from the user or something
for (int i = 0; i < addr; i++) {
    mask = mask >> 1; // move bits to the right
    mask = mask | 0x80000000; // hexadecimal notation, set the 31st bit
}
```

Now, mask is a (32-bit) integer with appropriate number of bits set. Now, converting it to decimal is easy. For example:

```
int fourth = mask & 0xff; // take the rightmost byte
int third = (mask >> 8) & 0xff; // move to the right by one byte, take the new rightmost byte
int second = (mask >> 16) & 0xff; // move by two bytes
int first = (mask >> 24) & 0xff;
```

Now, the mask is first.second.third.fourth

Hope this clears it up, take look at bitwise operators and try to wrap your head around them :)

Comment: So if my addr=4 , that for will add 4 1s at the beginind of the mask and the | 0x80000000  will create a 32-bit integer like 11110000.00000000.00000000.00000000 ?

Comment: Yeah, first it sets the 31st bit using bitwise-or (mask = mask | 0x80000000), then on the next iteration of the loop it moves all the bits to the right (mask = mask >> 1) so then only the 30th bit is set. After that it sets bit number 31 again (so bits 31 and 30 are set). You just have to make sure that the int type can hold 32 bits (4 bytes), maybe include stdint.h and use uint32_t